# Saving & using verbose sentence with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I getting a message like `-мотив Sample verbose text` and I need to save all after `-мотив`, but I don't know how to do this.

I tried use `@bot.command(pass_context=True)` and use arg, but it's not what I want.

Tried `async def мотив(ctx, message): text=message.content`, but it's not working too.

Help me pls for save all message after command, not one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand your question very well but I guess that you're trying to append all the words after `-мотив` in the parameter `message`. You can use `*` to do that. Here's an example:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def мотив(ctx, *, message):
    print(message)
```

So, when you type `-мотив test command 12`, it will print `test command 12` to the console.